# Is containerized monolithic less scalable than microservice?

Tags: docker, containers, microservices, monolithic

Apart from the other advantages of microservice, i dont understand the scaling argument. Sure, microservice can scale better than monolithic, but if you ***containerize*** monolithic, it should scale just like microservie, right?

For example, you have 100 containers available and the customer service is used 80% of the time and the product service is used 20% of the time,

- In microservice, there would be 80 containers of customer service and 20 containers of product service
- In containerized monolithic, there would be 100 containers of the monolith app, processing 80% customer service and 20% product service requests

So containerized monolithic would be just as scalable as microservice if i didnt miss anything.

Comment: By specializing the different parts your resource usage may be lower.

Comment: Did you also consider the spin up time of that giant monolith container? 100 containers of monolith and 80 containers of **CustomerService**, just imagine.

Answer (score -2):

Microservices are about scaling the organization. It's easier to have 500 developers working together if each team can work in isolation, so you have each 5-person team work on their own microservice.

Mostly it's nothing to do with scaling performance-wise.